# How can I use LazyLoading with WCF without causing circular references?

Tags: c#, wcf, architecture, mvvm, lazy-loading

I am doing validation using `DataAnnotation` attributes on the Model classes, and the Model class is used for validation on both the Client and Server side of the application.

My problem is, I can't figure out how to lazy load my Model's properties without causing circular references

The libraries involved are:

- WCF Service Library
- Client-Side DataAccess Library
- Models Library

Because the Models library is used on both the Client and Server side for data validation, I cannot reference the DataAccess library from within the Models library. Therefore, how can I setup lazy-loading?

For example, I have a ConsumerModel which has a property of PhoneNumbers which should be lazy loaded. How can I load the PhoneNumberModels from within the ConsumerModel without referencing the Client-Side DAL?

Client-side DAL:

```
using MyModels;

public class ConsumerDataAccess
{
    public ConsumerModel GetConsumerById(int id)
    {
        ConsumerDTO dto = WCFService.GetConsumer(id);
        return new ConsumerModel(dto);
    }
}
```

ConsumerModel:

```
public class ConsumerModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PhoneNumberModel> _phoneNumbers;

    public ObservableCollection<PhoneNumberModel> PhoneNumbers
    {
        get
        {
            if (_phoneNumbers == null)
            {
                // Can't reference DataAccess Library since that would cause a Circular Reference
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What are some alternative ways I could make this architecture work?

I would prefer to keep Validation with the Models, and to use the models from both the Client and Server side for validation. I would also prefer to keep using DataAnnotation for Validation.

**EDIT**

Here's my final solution based on Lawrence Wenham's answer if anyone is interested. I ended up using a delegate instead of an event.

DAL:

```
public class ConsumerDataAccess
{
    public ConsumerModel GetConsumerById(int id)
    {
        ConsumerDTO dto = WCFService.GetConsumer(id);
        ConsumerModel rtnValue = new ConsumerModel(dto);
        ConsumerModel.LazyLoadData = LazyLoadConsumerData;
        return rtnValue;
    }
}

private object LazyLoadConsumerData(string key, object args)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case "Phones":
            return PhoneDataAccess.GetByConsumerId((int)args);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Model Library:

```
public class ConsumerModel
{
    public delegate object LazyLoadDataDelegate(string id, object args);
    public LazyLoadDataDelegate LazyLoadData { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<PhoneNumberModel> _phoneNumbers;

    public ObservableCollection<PhoneNumberModel> PhoneNumbers
    {
        get
        {
            if (_phoneNumbers == null && LazyLoadData != null)
            {
                _phoneNumbers = (ObservableCollection<PhoneNumberModel>)
                        LazyLoadData("Phones", ConsumerId);
            }
            return _phoneNumbers;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way might be to raise an event in the `get {}` of your Model classes properties, and then implement a lazy-loading manager on the client side that has a reference to your DAL. EG:

```
public class LazyLoadEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public object Data { get; set; }

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public int Key { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your Model classes:

```
public event EventHandler<LazyLoadEventArgs> LazyLoadData;

public ObservableCollection<PhoneNumberModel> PhoneNumbers
{
    get
    {
        if (_phoneNumbers == null)
        {
            LazyLoadEventArgs args = new LazyLoadEventArgs {
                PropertyName = "PhoneNumbers",
                Key = this.Id
            };
            LazyLoadData(this, args);
            if (args.Data != null)
               this._phoneNumbers = args.Data as ObservableCollection<PhoneNumberModel>;
        }
        return _phoneNumbers;
    }
}
```

The handler for the LazyLoadData event would have the job of fetching the data from the client side's DAL, then storing it in the `.Data` property of LazyLoadEventArgs. EG:

```
private void Model_HandleLazyLoadData(object sender, LazyLoadEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "PhoneNumbers":
            e.Data = DAL.LoadPhoneNumbers(e.Key);
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... what actually calls the DAL to load the PhoneNumber data?

Comment: See edited answer. The event handler for LazyLoadData is what calls the DAL. You'll need to figure out the best way of identifying what data to load; in my example I just used a string and a 'Key' of some kind, but you could use enums, combine it with things like `if (sender is ConsumerModel)`, and so-on. It would keep the DAL out of the Model.

Comment: Wouldn't that still give me a circular reference problem? Models need to know about the Observers library, and Observers need to know about the Models library. My original problem is that I can't reference the DAL from the Model library, so I can't combine the two.

Comment: No, it shouldn't, because you'd put the event handler outside of the Models library. Whenever you fetch an object from the service, you'd attach the handler on the object before you do anything more with it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "lazy loading" with WCF. Network communication is time expensive. If you plan to use `PhoneNumbers` your service should expose method which will return `Customer` with phone numbers. Other approach is using [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx) which offers client side linq queries with ability to define eager loading by `Expand` method.

You should reduce service calls to minimum.

After reading again your question I don't understand why do you share model between service and client. Model is strictly client's feature. The only shared part should be DTOs.

Comment: PhoneNumbers was a simple example. A better example might have been Documents since in most cases documents are large files and I don't want to retrieve them in every situation. Users can customize their UI, so a user that has the Documents section on their screen needs to load Docs, while other users do not.

Comment: Sounds to me like different views which have different models and different methods to retrieve data.

Comment: There is a different view for each section of data. Users can drag/drop panels onto their screen depending on what information they need to work with. In almost all cases, the panels contain information relating to the consumer. When they load a Consumer, I need to load only the information that is located on their screen based on what panels they have on their screen.

Comment: In such case use event based model provided by @Lawrence (or any implementation of Observer pattern).

Comment: I saw your update. I wanted to use the Model Validation on both the Client and Server side of the application.